# Not able to get the variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, greasemonkey

I am writing a script in greasemonkey to automate some tasks, I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName('dealTitleTwoLine');
var s = n[0].attributes[2];
console.log(s);
```

This gives me the output

```
href="some string that I want to use"
```

I want to use only the value of href. I have tried doing:-

```
var s = n[0].attributes[2]['href'];
```

it returns undefined on the console.log. Just so that I am covering base, I have tried

```
var s = n[0].attributes[2].href;
```

This also returns undefined on console.log.

For the sake of redundancy, I have also tried:-
    var q = s.slice(5);

It doesnt return anything. Is there something that I am missing? I read the documentation of greasemonkey to check if thats the limiting factor but its not.

Comment: `n[0].getAttribute('href')`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that doesn't work in all cases

Comment: @Adelin Please clarify.

Comment: See [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

Comment: @Adelin I thought the question was specific for the `href` attribute. For just accessing the value of a numbered attribute `n[0].attributes[2].value`

Answer (score -1):

You can access an element's attributes using the `getAttribute` method.

So just use the following code and you should be good to go:

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName('dealTitleTwoLine');
var s = n[0].getAttribute('href');
```

You can find more information about this method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Hope it helps!!